# Parse a single CSV string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, csv

Is there a way that I can parse a single comma delimited string without using anything fancy like a csv.reader(..) ? I can use the `split(',')` function but that doesn't work when a valid column value contains a comma itself. The csv library has readers for parsing CSV files which correctly handle the aforementioned special case, but I can't use those because I need to parse just a single string. However if the Python CSV allows parsing a single string itself then that's news to me.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Take a closer look at the documentation for the `csv` module, which
says:

```
reader(...)
    csv_reader = reader(iterable [, dialect='excel']
                            [optional keyword args])
        for row in csv_reader:
            process(row)

    The "iterable" argument can be any object that returns a line
    of input for each iteration, such as a file object or a list.  The
    optional "dialect" parameter is discussed below.  The function
    also accepts optional keyword arguments which override settings
    provided by the dialect.
```

So if you have string:

```
>>> s = '"this is", "a test", "of the csv", "parser"'
```

And you want "an object that returns a line of input for each
iteration", you can just wrap your string in a list:

```
>>> r = csv.reader([s])
>>> list(r)
[['this is', 'a test', 'of the csv parser']]
```

And that's how you parse a string with the `csv` module.

Comment: I guess it would be more elegant to use `iter(s)` as to a general iterator instead of `[s]` (specifying a list). But you have my +1

Comment: This probably won't work if the string has quoted linefeeds inside of the values; @alecxe's answer makes more sense

Comment: `list(csv.reader(['"this is", "a test", "of the csv", "parser"']))[0]` Boom!

Comment: @rafaelc is more elegant but will give you wrong results

Answer (score 23):

You can still parse a single string with `csv`. Use StringIO to write a string [buffer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO) (also known as *memory files*):

```
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO

s = "your string"
buff = StringIO(s)

reader = csv.reader(buff)
for line in reader:
    print(line)
```

Comment: For Python 3 use `from io import StringIO` see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o)

Comment: But be careful with non-ASCII strings! *'If [Unicode and 8-bit strings] are used, 8-bit strings that cannot be interpreted as 7-bit ASCII (that use the 8th bit) will cause a UnicodeError to be raised when getvalue() is called.'*

Answer (score 14):

```
>>> import csv
>>> s = '"Yes, this line",can be, parsed as csv'
>>> list(csv.reader([s]))[0]
['Yes, this line', 'can be', ' parsed as csv']
>>>
```

Basically just @larsks answer above but more brief and demonstrating that it works on csv values that have commas inside quotes.

If you upvote me, upvote the other answer too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35822856/1196339

Answer (score 1):

String to Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv_str="Column1,Column2\n1,2\n3,4"

buff = StringIO(csv_str)
df = pd.read_csv(buff)
```

DataFrame:

```
Out[1]: 
   Column1  Column2
         1        2
         3        4
```

For other delimiters add something like `delimiter="\t"` to `read_csv()`.